# send CONNECT with User-Agent C#

Tags: c#, https, websocket

I'm trying to automate a WebSocket service that denies connection unless you send a user agent with the CONNECT request.

I tried sending the upgrade request with HttpWebRequest and setting User-Agent using the property.

Using Fiddler to debug the request this was sent out:

```
CONNECT *.*.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: *.*.com:443
Connection: keep-alive
```

How do I add the User-Agent string to the CONNECT request and then upgrade to using WebSocket protocol?

My code so far:

```
public void Login ( Action onEnd = null ) {
    var req = CreateUpgradeRequest();
    var res = GetResponse(req);
}

private HttpWebRequest CreateUpgradeRequest ( ) {
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://lobby35.runescape.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36";
    request.Connection = "Upgrade";
    SetWebSocketHeader(request, "Key", "5LENZfSifyj/Rw1ghTvpgw==");
    SetWebSocketHeader(request, "Version", "13");
    SetWebSocketHeader(request, "Extensions", "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits");
    SetWebSocketHeader(request, "Protocol", "jagex");

    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `WebRequest` to create a websocket connection. You will need [`ClientWebSocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket(v=vs.110).aspx) and use [`ClientWebSocket.Options.SetRequestHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocketoptions.setrequestheader(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note, you may have issues adding that header: [Setting "User-Agent" HTTP header in ClientWebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22635663/setting-user-agent-http-header-in-clientwebsocket)

Update: Since you cannot add that header with `ClientWebSocket` try with [Websocket4Net](http://websocket4net.codeplex.com/workitem/21).

Comment: took a look at that solution but it doesn't add the User-Agent to the connect request

Comment: I updated the post with a link to WebSocket4Net example.