# How do I set a default User Agent on an HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net

It's easy to [set a user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659663/how-to-set-user-agent-with-system-net-webrequest-in-c-sharp) on an `HttpRequest`, but often I want to use a single `HttpClient` and use the same user agent every time, rather than having to set it on each request.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Using `DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(...)` did not work for me.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AcmeInc/1.0)");
```

Comment: I did this with word-word-name.name@domain.com and it failed , it expects a more standard format UA so I changed it to Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; word-word-name.name@domain.com)

Answer (score 152):

You can solve this easily using:

```
HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "C# App");
```

Answer (score 19):

The following worked for me in a .NET Standard 2.0 library:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
ProductHeaderValue header = new ProductHeaderValue("MyAwesomeLibrary", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString());
ProductInfoHeaderValue userAgent = new ProductInfoHeaderValue(header);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(userAgent);
// User-Agent: MyAwesomeLibrary/1.0.0.0
```

Comment: Short addition: The ```UserAgent``` class also offers ```TryParse```, which comes especially handy when there is no version number (for whatever reason). The RFC explicitly allows this case.

Answer (score 18):

Using [JensG comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076962/how-do-i-set-a-default-user-agent-on-an-httpclient/59956957#comment98612630_54844585)

> Short addition: The UserAgent class also offers TryParse, which comes especially handy when there is no version number (for whatever reason). The RFC explicitly allows this case.

on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54844585/185123)

```cs
using System.Net.Http;
```

```cs
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders
      .UserAgent
      .TryParseAdd("Mike D's Agent");
    //User-Agent: Mike D's Agent
}
```

Comment: i think that code line actually does nothing at all, except returning false?

Answer (score 0):

```
string agent="ClientDemo/1.0.0.1 test user agent DefaultRequestHeaders";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", agent);
```

remark: use this structure to generate the agent name
User-Agent: product / product-version comment

> - product:  Product identifier
> - product-version:   Product version number.
> - comment: None or more of the infomation Comments containing product, for example.

[references](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: The comment should be enclosed in "(" and ")".