# Response returns 302(redirect) but the Location property is empty

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am trying to get the stream from this particular image (https://www.paymentscardsandmobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/identity-1-1.jpg) using the following code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, fileUrl))
            {
                
               var stream = await (await client.SendAsync(request)).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            }
        }
```

The request returns an error with status code 302, but the location property is empty:
[image]

My question is: How does the browser know how to load the image correctly? And is there something wrong with my code? because it works as expected with different images.

Comment: Can we see the code where you build URL/`fileUrl`?

Comment: `await (await client.SendAsync(request)).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();`

I have never seen this syntax before for both sending request and awaiting response, interesting

Comment: I've tested the URL you have provided with two redirect checker sites and neither of them return 302. The file is returned with a 200 status code.

Comment: @thesystem, the fileUrl is just a string, and it is the URL of the image i have provided in the question.

Comment: @Llama I have tested it with postman and it returns 200 as well, which is weird. The code otherwise works as expected with different urls.

Comment: I'm going to hazard a guess: the website excepts some header (perhaps `User-Agent`) that isn't being sent by your request. It therefore redirects you to somewhere else without giving you the result.

Comment: I've tested my theory and confirm that that is indeed what happens. Looking at the resulting request in Fiddler Classic, we can see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaviP.png). The location returned by the server actually is `http://0.0.0.0`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50057689/3181933) should solve your problem.

Comment: @Llama that was it! I added this header to the request and it worked:

 request.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; " +
                                    "Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

Comment: @Llama can you answer this question so that I can select it as accepted. thank you again.

Comment: It seems better to close it as a duplicate, but I can't vote to do that now having previously voted to close it for a different reason. You can add an answer yourself if you wish.