# Image isn't displayed from URL

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, https

I'm a little bit confused, because it's not the first time I'm using it this way.
I have a DataGrid and defined the Columns by using DataGridTemplateColumns.
One column should display an image from https.
My XAML for that Image looks this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ArticleImage">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Height="50" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I compared this to my other projects where this works fine with the same data base of urls.
In this Project the image isn't shown, I got only a blank cell.

I copied the content of the ImagePath and paste it into my browser, what's working fine.

I also tried using an BitmapImage as shown in other threads but that doesn't work, too.
As the code shown above works in other projects *( all C#, same Framework! )* my confusing rises.

Has anyone an idea of what I'm not seeing?

**EDIT:** an additional information:
If I place a textblock instead of the image, the text displays the correct and conmplete Url!

Thanks

Comment: Try calling downloading the file in your application like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71949994/2598770 - does it raise an exception?

Comment: Yes, it results 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable), but it runs in browser?!

Comment: the domain is blocking the user-agent, try changing the default user agent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44076962/how-do-i-set-a-default-user-agent-on-an-httpclient

Comment: It's the same, tried both examples from your link. Already 503.

Comment: can you share the url? makes it easier to figure out what is going wrong

Comment: e.g.: https://media.weidezaun.info/Artikelbilder/Shop50px/503400-wasser-futtertrog-45l-001.jpg

Comment: Can't replicate the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAWYg.png

Comment: That's weird. I'm getting 503 furthermore ?
Thanks for testing @Rand Random

Comment: @A.Drews I am seeing the same problem here. If I use a different URL everything works as expected.

Comment: So you get an 503 with my posted link?

Comment: @A.Drews with you URL the image doesn't show up.

Comment: Thanks for testing too. Makes me more weired as before, but nice to know :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to the local antivirus program. We use Bitdefender here and it doesn't work on the computers. If I start the application from a server that doesn't have BitDefender installed, it works with exactly the same code.

Comment: I do not use BitDefender here and it doesn't work.