# Is there any way to set "restricted" headers in PowerShell's Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to call a REST service that requires a `Date` header in the request.  When I try something like

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "http://path/to/my/service" -Header @{"Date"="Fri, 20 Mar 2015 16:00:00 GMT"}
```

I get an error

> The 'Date' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239725/cannot-set-some-http-headers-when-using-system-net-webrequest) which addresses similar problems with a WebRequest in C#.  I can't use `HeaderProperty` here (which appears to be the C# fix) -- is there anything else, or am I just unable to call this service from PowerShell?

Comment: It seems that this property can be modified in HttpWebRequest class only if you use .NET 4.0 or above - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.date.aspx. I think that Invoke-RestMethod use HttpWebRequest class for requests. I run your code using powershell 4.0 without any errors. There are some solutions on stackoverflow about how to run old version of powershell with .NET 4.0, for example.

Comment: The output of `$PSVersionTable` includes `CLRVersion = 4.0.30319.18063`.  The `PSVersion` is 3.0 -- maybe it also needs to be PS 4.0+?

Comment: Try to update version to 4.0. It's possible for Windows 7 (Windows 2008).

Comment: Corporate IT, out of my control.  If it does turn out to be a version-of-powershell thing, then I guess I'm stuck with writing Actual Code :-/