# "Unable to cast" subcommand return value?

Tags: rest, powershell

I'm trying to call `Invoke-RestMethod` (and running into [another unrelated problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29169848/is-there-any-way-to-set-restricted-headers-in-powershells-invoke-restmethod)) and keep getting errors when trying to pass it the result of a sub-command.  Consider:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Header @{"Iso-Date"=(Get-Date -Format "r")}
```

I expect this to run `Get-Date -Format "r"`, assign its output string (the ISO-format date) to the hashtable value for `Iso-Date`, then use that hashtable as the "Header" argument for the commandlet.

What actually happens is I get an error message

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'System.String'.

This still happens if I assign it to a variable:

```
$date = (Get-Date -Format "r")
$date.GetType() # -- outputs "String"
Invoke-RestMethod -Header @{"Iso-Date"=$date) # -- Same error message.
```

If I set `$date` to a fixed string value, I don't get the error anymore:

```
$date = "Fri, 20 Mar 2015 16:00:00 GMT"
$date.GetType() # -- outputs "String" as well (!!!)
Invoke-RestMethod -Header @{"Iso-Date"=$date) # -- works fine
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A few additional minutes with Google lead me to try, out of sheer desperation, `$date = (Get-Date -Format "r").ToString()`.  This works, but I still have no idea why and would like to know a) where I went wrong and b) how to tell when I can expect to need ToString() in the future

Comment: Interesting. `(get-date -format "r") -is [PSObject]` returns `True`, but `("{0:r}" -f (get-date)) -is [PSObject]` returns `False`.

Comment: I believe it may be due to version of .Net/Powershell that is installed. I do not get any errors when I try `Invoke-RestMethod -Header @{"Iso-Date"=(Get-Date -Format "r")}`. Running .Net 4.5.1 and Powershell 5.0 here. Bill_Stewart's `PSObject` tests still hold true with my setup, but the hashtable value assignment is successful.