# Can't I set If-Modified-Since on a WebClient?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, if-modified-since

I am using `WebClient` to retrieve a website. I decided to set `If-Modified-Since` because if the website hasn't changed, I don't want to get it again:

```
var c = new WebClient();
c.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = Last_refreshed.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r");
```

Where `Last_refreshed` is a variable in which I store the time I've last seen the website.

But when I run this, I get a `WebException` with the text:

```
The 'If-Modified-Since' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name
```

Turns out the [API docs mention this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> In addition, some other headers are also restricted when using a `WebClient` object. These restricted headers include, but are not limited to the following:
>
> - Accept
> - Connection
> - Content-Length
> - Expect (when the value is set to "100-continue")
> - If-Modified-Since
> - Range
> - Transfer-Encoding
>
> The `HttpWebRequest` class has properties for setting some of the above headers. If it is important for an application to set these headers, then the `HttpWebRequest` class should be used instead of the `WebRequest` class.

So does this mean there's no way to set them from `WebClient`? Why not? What's wrong with specifying `If-Modified-Since` in a normal `HTTP GET`?

I know I can just use `HttpWebRequest`, but I don't want to because it's too much work (have to do a bunch of casting, can't just get the content as a string).

Also, I know [Cannot set some HTTP headers when using System.Net.WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239725/) is related, but it doesn't actually answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

As unwieldy as it may be, I have opted to subclass `WebClient` in order to add the functionality in a way that mimics the way `WebClient` typically works (in which headers are consumed by / reset after each use):

```
public class ApiWebClient : WebClient {
  public DateTime? IfModifiedSince { get; set; }

  protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address) {
    var webRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address);
    var httpWebRequest = webRequest as HttpWebRequest;
    if (httpWebRequest != null) {
      if (IfModifiedSince != null) {
        httpWebRequest.IfModifiedSince = IfModifiedSince.Value;
        IfModifiedSince = null;
      }
      // Handle other headers or properties here
    }
    return webRequest;
  }
}
```

This has the advantage of not having to write boilerplate for the standard operations that WebClient provides, while still offering some of the flexibility of using WebRequest.