# How to correctly add WebRequest header?

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

```
var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://vtopbeta.vit.ac.in/vtop/");
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
webRequest.Headers.Add("User-Agent",
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36");
string jsonResponse;
using (var s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(s ?? throw new InvalidOperationException()))
    {
        jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

I wrote this yesterday and it worked just fine. Today suddenly this is not working anymore. There is an almost exact question [Cannot set some HTTP headers when using System.Net.WebRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239725/cannot-set-some-http-headers-when-using-system-net-webrequest) but the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4752359/4427870 says I cant use `User-Agent` header but I literally used it a day before.

The error I get: `System.ArgumentException: 'The 'User-Agent' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name'`

I'd like to use `WebRequest` and not `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `UserAgent` directly, use [`CreateHttp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.createhttp?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead which returns `HttpWebRequest`, then you can do:

```
webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36";
```

`UserAgent` is a restricted header and must be set via a property, there is a list of all restricted headers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.headers?view=netframework-4.7.2).